# How to do a 301 redirect from http to https in a domino server?

Tags: http, redirect, https, ibm-domino

I need to do a 301 redirect from http://www.example.com to https://www.example.com

The Internet site document option that does a TCP to SSL redirect is a response with http code 302.

Does setting this option off and adding a Redirect Web Site Rule to this domain work?

Answer (score 2):

The 'Redirect TCP to SSL' option is on the **Security** tab of the *WebSite/Internet Site* document.  However, I just checked this with Fiddler and it uses a 302 response code, not a 301.

Open the Internet Sites doc in question and click the *Web Site... -> Create Rule* button.  Set the following field values:

- *Description*: 301 Redir to SSL
- *Type of rule*: Redirection
- *Incoming URL pattern*: /*
- *Redirect to this URL*: https://www.example.com/*
- *Send 301 Redirect*: (checked)

Be sure to restart the HTTP task for these changes to take effect.

Further documentation on this can be found at the following links:
[Creating a Web Site Rule document](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/domhelp/v8r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.help.domino.admin85.doc/H_WEB_SITE_RULES.html)
[Http 301 Redirection](http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/nd85forum.nsf/0/00f6ee772931e17f85257a0800583e31?OpenDocument)

Comment: I thought this would work and I did try on a production site but it does something that I conceptually thought might happen. It gets into a loop of https requests to "https://www.example.com/".

Comment: Odd - had you previously indicated a successful test on a dev/test server?  If so, is the prod server running a different version of Domino?  I successfully tested this (without the looping) on Domino 8.5.1 FP3 (64-bit).

Answer (score 0):

Did you use Internet Site?
"Load Internet configurations from Server\Internet Sites documents: Enabled"
or not?

Did you tried the following:

1.) Open the Server Document
2.) Ports -> Internet Ports -> Web -> TCP/IP port Status: Redirect to SSL
3.) Wait until the changes are replicated and recognized by the server
4.) restart HTTP (or better the whole server)

Or are you refering to internet sites?

Note:
302: move temporary
301: moved permanently

Comment: I do use internet sites, but I don't know where "Load Internet configurations from Server\Internet Sites documents: Enabled" setting is.

Comment: For the second point you made, if I make the change will it not be set for any request to any host that the server is servicing. I want it set for just one host and I want it to be a 301 for that host only.

Comment: The "Load Internet configurations from Server\Internet Sites documents" setting is on the Basics tab of the Server document.  Check the topmost section on that tab, left-hand column of settings.